# Sum of cost amount calculation

Tags: database, filemaker

I have attached the screenshot. Most probably that the image itself will explain my logic. Let me paste the code I have used in the fields. Product `Info1` field which hold `Y` & `N`.

```
RemainingCosu2=If(Invoice Line Items::Product Info1  = GetAsText ("N"); Sum(Cost Total) - Invoice Line Items::VendPaid_total;0)
RemainingCosu1=If(Vendor Status="Partly Paid"; RemainingCosu2; 0)
```

What should I do to fix this issue?. Please check the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filemaker has no SumIf() function. You need to create a calculation field in the LineItems table, along the lines of:

```
If ( Paid = "N" ; Cost )
```

then sum this field at the invoice level (and/or summarize it at the LineItems table itself), instead of the Cost field.

--
BTW, it is much more convenient to define Boolean (yes/no) fields as Number and use the values of 1 for True, 0 (or empty) for False. Then the calculation can be simply:

```
   If ( not Paid ; Cost )
```

Comment: yes i changed the field to boolean variable. and got it worked.